# adding print preview for vb.net printing code

Tags: vb.net, printing, preview

update this function to add print preview and then a link(print) in the print preview to print the preview page

```
    function PrintPanel() {

        var panel = document.getElementById("<%=pnlContents.ClientID %>");

        var printWindow = window.open('', '', 'height=400,width=800');

        printWindow.document.write('<html><head><title>DIV Contents</title>');

        printWindow.document.write('</head><body >');

        printWindow.document.write(panel.innerHTML);

        printWindow.document.write('</body></html>');

        printWindow.document.close();

        setTimeout(function () {

            printWindow.print();

        }, 500);

        return false;

    }

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the built in print Preview  control for displaying the print preview in the form. see the screen shot for placing the print preview control in the form 
[image: selected item is the control and the gray colored region is the preview area]